# Pythonic way to process multiple for loops with different filters against the same list?

Tags: python, list, iterator, idioms

Here's a bit of a program I'm writing that will create a csv categorizing a directory of files:

```
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*[A-Z]*'):
        matches.append([os.path.join(root, filename), "No Capital Letters!"])

    test = re.compile(".*\.(py|php)", re.IGNORECASE)
    for filename in filter(test.search, filenames):
        matches.append([os.path.join(root, filename), "Invalid File type!"])
```

Basically, the user picks a folder and the program denotes problem files, which can be of several types (just two listed here: no files with uppercase letters, no php or python files). There will be probably five or six cases.

While this works, I want to refactor. Is it possible to do something like

```
for filename in itertools.izip(fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*[A-Z]*'), filter(test.search, filenames), ...):
    matches.append([os.path.join(root, filename), "Violation")
```

while being able to keep track of which of original unzipped lists caused the "violation?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler solution would probably be to just iterate over the files first and then apply your checks one by one:

```
reTest = re.compile(".*\.(py|php)", re.IGNORECASE)
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        error = None
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*[A-Z]*'):
            error = 'No capital letters!'
        elif reTest.search(filename):
            error = 'Invalid file type!'

        if error:
            matches.append([os.path.join(root, filename), error])
```

This will not only make the logic a lot simpler since you only ever need to check a single file (instead of having to figure every time out how to call your check method on a sequence of filenames), it will also iterate only once through the list of filenames.

Furthermore, it will also avoid generating multiple matches for a single file name; it just adds one error (the first) at most. If you don’t want this, you could make `error` a list instead and append to it in your checks—of course you want to change the `elif` to `if` then to evaluate all the checks.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you look at [these slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf).

David Beazley gives an example of using `yield` to process log files.

edit: here are two examples from the pdf, one without generator:

```
wwwlog = open("access-log")
total = 0
for line in wwwlog:
  bytestr = line.rsplit(None,1)[1]
   if bytestr != '-':
     total += int(bytestr)
 print "Total", total
```

and with generator (can use function with yield for more complex examples)

```
wwwlog = open("access-log")
bytecolumn = (line.rsplit(None,1)[1] for line in wwwlog)
bytes = (int(x) for x in bytecolumn if x != '-')
print "Total", sum(bytes)
```

Comment: Updated with example. Agreed link-only answers aren't as good.